# Why doesn't sbt automatically add libraryDependencies to class path?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

Why doesn't sbt automatically add libraryDependencies to class path? I am trying to add jdbc-sqlite to my project however it can't find the driver. The lib dependency is being managed by sbt so it should be part of the class path. But I guess not, so how can I add it?

It feels like bad practice to have defined path references to these libraries that only exist on my box.

```
name := "CacheWarmer"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

mainClass in Compile := Some("process.Daemon")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.20.0" % "test"
)

package process

import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Statement
```

Code

```
object Daemon {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //Gets java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite::memory:
    val connection:Connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:")
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course compile/runtime dependencies are available in the sbt run & test classpath.

Comment: Not according to my run time which says it can't find my jdbc-sqlite driver

Answer (score 2):

You have put the `sqlite-jdbc` dependency into the `test` scope. Naturally, such dependencies are only available in the test classpath, but not in the "main" classpath. Usually you use the `test` scope for test dependencies, e.g. test libraries like Scalatest or JUnit.

In order for a library to be available in your "main" classpath, you have to use the `compile` scope, or, equivalently, not using a scope classifier at all:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.20.0"
)
```

Comment: They don't have a scala version tacked on which results in the issue no suitable scala version found.

Comment: @Dr.Knowitall sorry, my bad, should've removed the `%%` in favor of `%`. Since this is a pure Java library, there is no need to append Scala binary version to it, which is exactly what `%%` does. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maven central tells that to use that dependency in SBT you should use:

`libraryDependencies += "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.20.0"` --> Notice there is no double `%`

The `%%` tells sbt to append the current scala version to the artifact name. Assuming you are running scala 2.11:

`libraryDependencies += "org.some" %% "myscala" % "3.20.0"`

gets desuggered to:

```
`libraryDependencies += "org.some" % "myscala_2.11" % "3.20.0"`
```